# Html to docx with Docx4j break table when page skip

Tags: java, docx4j, html-to-docx

I using docx4j to generated a docx from html string, works great but the tables broken when the page skip.

[image: Table broken]

This the code.

```
WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.createPackage();

XHTMLImporterImpl XHTMLImporter = new XHTMLImporterImpl(wordMLPackage);

//File is a htmlStringFile 
wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().getContent().addAll(XHTMLImporter.convert(file, null) );

File fileDos = new File(urlWord);
```

I´m using a docx4j 8.3.2 with Java 8.

Somebody know how to change all properties in the general document ?
Example : space between paragraph, space after the line,

Another problem, in some case the table cell add diferent space between cell. I don´t know why

[image: cell add diferent space]

Comment: You mean when a table cell contains enough content to flow over onto the next page?  Can the problem be reproduced with a simple 1x1 table?

Comment: When the tables broken in the page break, the tables properties in word.exe set "specify height",  how to dissabled that property in docx4j ??

Comment: @JasonPlutext when the cell contains enough text and go to the next page, the table it broken. I see in word.exe it add that property ""specify height" how to set this in docx4 ? It´s posible ?